# Excel automatically converts to date?

Tags: excel, date

I have an excel file that always converts k 6-8 to a date. Is there anyway to not make this happen? I have tried making a plain text field to prevent this and still no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a tick in front of it so instead of k 6-8 do 'k 6-8

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an apostrophe (') before the 6-8 to force it to text.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an space before the 6-8 to force it to text.("6-8" as " 6-8" --- notice space)